# UISearchBar puts full stop after adding more than one space

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I am getting strange behaviour from UISearchBar. When I press more that one space in UISearchBar, it automatically puts full stop "." in search bar text. I do not understand why this is happening. Here is my code,

```
 NSString *str = [searchBar.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                 [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];


NSLog(@"%@",searchBar.text );
```

I press space and then f and then 2 times space and it puts full stop. Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a property of iOS, not the UISearchBar element.

It is configurable as " '.' Shortcut" in General -> Keyboard in the Settings part of iOS. It's description: "Double tapping the space bar will insert a period followed by a space."

As for programmatically removing the period/full stop, i guess you could do that with regexes, but I wouldn't recommend it. Because the feature is part of the user preferences for the keyboard, it will act the same, no matter what app you are using. It's kind of like changing all the text that the user types to uppercase, they may not want it that way (or they may be used to double tapping shift), so your app becomes confusing and hard to use.

I would say just leave it as is.

Comment: How can I change this because I do not want full stop.

Comment: Your answer is correct just tell me how can I remove this full sop programatically.

Comment: I don't think you can, as this is a user's configuration. They choose to activate it everywhere or nowhere, so the behavior is the same on every app.

Comment: BTW, you don't seem to know that : if you insert a space, then wait a couple seconds, and hit space again, it will not put a period but two spaces, and you can tap the space bar repeatedly without iOS adding a period, until you write a character. For example, type "hello", then space, then wait, then you can hit as many times as you want the space bar, it will insert only spaces. The comportment will revert to "two spaces = period+space" when you type a character (e.g. "a", "b", ...).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to remove the automatic addition of full stop,

For UISearchBar you can overwrite,

```
- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    if ([text isEqualToString:@". "]) {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

For UITextField you can do the same but overwrite the following instead,

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
```

Comment: This doesn't work on iOS 16. The period is NOT included in "text" string.

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 16 the only way to disable this without turning it off for the keyboard entirely (which the user can do themselves in iOS Settings) is to disallow two consecutive spaces in the `UISearchBar`. You can do this like so:

```
-(BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    // Looks for user entering 2 spaces in a row, if we allow it then after return from this iOS will replace the
    // previous space with a period. This blocks two spaces in a row.
    if((range.location > 0 && [text length] > 0 &&
        [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[text characterAtIndex:0]] &&
        [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[[searchBar text] characterAtIndex:range.location - 1]])
    ){
        searchBar.text = [searchBar.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@" "];
            
       // Disallow the second space. If you allow it a '.' will be inserted AFTER you return from this.
       return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```